# C programming code error

Tags: c

So the program is still incomplete, i cant go any further cause there is an error right after the first input, i tried using visual studio 2010 and 2015, both with the same problem:

> unhandled exception at 0x60eae42e (msvcr100d.dll) in asd.exe: 0xc0000005: Access violation writing location 0xccccccccc

so can any find the problem in this? or test and see if its working on your pc? this code is supposed to be c

```
int main()
{
    int y[3][3], inv[3][3], co[3][3], d[3], sol[3], D = 0,i=0, j = 0;
    char z;
    start: // Used to restart the program when the persons want to do more work or has done an error
    printf("The format for the linear equation is\na1.X + b1.Y + c1.Z = d1\na2.X + b2.Y + c2.Z = d2\na3.X + b3.Y + c3.Z = d3\n");
    for (i = 0;i < 3;i++)
    {
        for (z = 'a';z < 'd';z++,j++)
        {
            printf("Enter the value for %c%i\n", z, i + 1);
            scanf("%i", y[i][j]);
        }
        printf("Enter the valie for D%i\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%i", d[i]);
        j = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0;i < 3;i++)
        for (j = 0;j < 3;j++)
        co[i][j] = (y[(i + 1) % 3][(j + 1) % 3] * y[(i + 2) % 3][(j + 2) % 3]) - (y[(i + 1) % 3][(j + 2) % 3] * y[(i + 2) % 3][(j + 1) % 3]);
    for (i = 0;i < 3;i++)
        D += y[i][0] * co[i][0];
    if (D == 0)
    {
        printf("\nThese equations cannot be solved!\n");
    }
    for (i = 0;i < 3;i++)
        for (j = 0;j < 3;j++);
    for (i = 0;i < 3;i++)
        for (j = 0;j < 3;j++)
        inv[i][j] = co[i][j] / D;
    for (i = 0;i < 3;i++)
    {
        sol[i] = 0;
        for (j = 0;j < 3;j++)
            sol[i] += inv[i][j] * d[j];
    }
    printf("The solutions are\nX=%i\nY=%i\nZ=%i\n", sol[0], sol[1], sol[2]);
    getch();
    goto start;


}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0;i < 3;i++) for (j = 0;j < 3;j++);` o.0

Comment: `start: // Used to restart the program when the persons want to do more work or has done an error` Use a loop instead of using `goto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These:

```
scanf("%i", y[i][j]);
scanf("%i", d[i]);
```

needs to be:

```
scanf("%i", &y[i][j]);
scanf("%i", &d[i]);
```

as `%i` in the `scanf` expects an `int*`(address of the variable), not an `int`(value of the variable).

---

Another problem is that you do division by zero here:

```
inv[i][j] = co[i][j] / D;
```

when `D` is zero.